# In span of some days, memory climbs up to 90%, then stays there. Is that a memory leak? How to detect what processes use cached memory?

Tags: linux, memory, arch-linux

I have a NAS with a cutom web OS and tons of daemons running that together form a system to complement Mobotix IP cameras.

In the recent weeks, I'm having a bit of a problem - the built-in resource monitor shows memory usage increase at approximately 10% per day. Once it reaches 90%, it just sits there within a +/- 1% range.

I am also calculating, what I call, the optimized memory. That is, removed buffers and added cache, those stay at ~20% every day.

Output of `free` as of now:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached  
Mem:       1901072    1731036     170036          0     146228    1207360  
-/+ buffers/cache:     377448    1523624  
Swap:      1048572       1648    1046924
```

As you can see, memory is almost full, but the cached/buffered appears to be taking most of the memory.

I have a feeling, that this is caused due to a memory leak somewhere, but I'm not sure.

How do I detect what processes are filling the buffered/cached memory?

Comment: Why do you want memory to be free anyway? If you're thinking "I want it to be free now so I can use it later", forget it. You can use it now **and** use it later. There's **no** tradeoff to be made here. Free memory is no better than memory that isn't in your computer at all. Only memory that is being *used* impacts performance.

Comment: I do not care about it being free or full used or whatever, I was just uncertain what is causing this, and whether I should be on the lookout for fixing the potential issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a problem, Linux is supposed to do that. If you were really having memory problems, you would notice everything running slowly and processes getting killed by the [OOM killer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_memory).

The Linux kernel takes advantage of unused RAM for disk caching. This is a Good Thing, it makes everything run faster. This memory is still available to any program that needs it, it will only be used for caching if it is not needed elsewhere. That's why `free` shows `buffers/cache` separately, you should consider them as free memory.

The actual amount of memory available to your system is `free` + `buffers` + `cache`, in the example you've posted that's `170036 + 146228 + 1207360 = 1523624`, that's ~1.5G of free memory.

This is explained quite nicely in the [RedHat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Tuning_and_Optimizing_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_for_Oracle_9i_and_10g_Databases/chap-Oracle_9i_and_10g_Tuning_Guide-Memory_Usage_and_Page_Cache.html):

> In this example the total amount of available memory is 4040360 KB.
>   264224 KB are used by processes and 3776136 KB are free for other
>   applications. **Do not get confused by the first line which shows that
>   28160KB are free!** If you look at the usage figures you can see that
>   most of the memory use is for buffers and cache. **Linux always tries to
>   use RAM to speed up disk operations by using available memory for
>   buffers (file system metadata) and cache (pages with actual contents
>   of files or block devices).** This helps the system to run faster
>   because disk information is already in memory which saves I/O
>   operations. **If space is needed by programs or applications like
>   Oracle, then Linux will free up the buffers and cache to yield memory
>   for the applications.** If your system runs for a while you will usually
>   see a small number under the field "free" on the first line.

For more information see here:

- http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: Would give another plus for Linux Ate My Ram. Thanks for explanation, it's all clear now.